# Como obter o return de um método que depende de outro dentro de uma classe?

Tags: php, classes, return

Estou usando uma classe chamada `Semelhantes` que vai ter 2 métodos.

O `features` pega **3 características do imóvel atual** através da `id`.

O `resemblant` monta uma **query** que tem objetivo de trazer imóveis que se pareçam com o imóvel atual e mostra-os como uma espécie de **imóveis relacionados**.

Poderá observar no método `features` ao fim do mesmo que já consegui armazenar os atributos que vou usar para chamar a ***query*** através do método `resemblant`. Estes atributos estão armazenadas.

Estou enviando estes atributos para o método `resemblant` mas ao tentar chamar a informação conforme pode ser observado no fundo do código, instanciando o objeto e armazenando o resultado, não tenho o retorno do método.

> **Neste caso, como obter o retorno do método `resemblant()`?**

```
<?php 

require("Acesso.class.php");

class Semelhantes extends Acesso
{
    public function features($id)
    {
        $postFields  = '{"fields":["Codigo","Categoria","Bairro","Cidade","ValorVenda","ValorLocacao","Dormitorios","Suites","Vagas","AreaTotal","AreaPrivativa","Caracteristicas","InfraEstrutura"]}';
        $url         = 'http://danielbo-rest.vistahost.com.br/'.$this->vsimoveis.'/'.$this->vsdetalhes.'?key=' . $this->vskey;
        $url           .= '&imovel='.$id.'&pesquisa=' . $postFields;

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , array( 'Accept: application/json' ) );
        $result = curl_exec($ch); 
        $result = json_decode($result, true);

        /**
         * Paramentros para filtrar semelhança
         * @var [type]
         */
        $fcidade    = str_replace(" ", "+", $result['Cidade']);
        $fdorms     = $result['Dormitorios'];
        $fvalor     = $result['ValorVenda'];

        return array(
            'cidade' => $fcidade, 
            'dorms' => $fdorms, 
            'valor' => $fvalor
        );

    }

    public function resemblant()
    {
        $get = $this->features($id);
        return $get['Cidade'];
    }

}

/* Chamando as funções em outra parte do sistema */
$obj        = new Semelhantes;
$features   = $obj->features(2);
$similar    = $obj->resemblant();
```

Comment: @bigown a prova de que estou estudando é que já estou escrevendo corretamente, tipo, falando classes, métodos, atributos, objetos em vez de outros nomes tipo variáveis que não é o caso dentro de uma classe **:)**

Comment: Mas continua fazendo herança onde não existe hierarquia :D Usar o termos corretos é bom, mas usar os conceitos corretamente é absurdamente mais importante. Não estou com tempo para ver isto mas tem outras coisas estranhas na classe. Fora que neste momento a classe não está fazendo o código ficar melhor. Espero que depois isto aconteça, caso contrário é só desperdício de recurso.

Comment: @bigown Partindo do princípio que posso usar este módulo em vários lugares do sistema, mesmo assim ele não seria interessante dentro de uma classe aonde eu resgato só o retorno?

Comment: Me parece que não, mas não estou com tempo para analisar.

Comment: pelo que eu entendi @MarcosVinicius você quer chamar resemblant() dentro de features()? correto? você pode utilizar métodos estáticos se esse for o problema. Assim o método não seria chamado pela instância da classe e sim pelo nome dela, o que tornaria possível a chamada de um método sem a instanciação do objeto.

Comment: Não entendi o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simples ué, basta armazenar o parâmetro id numa variável da classe.

```
class Semelhantes extends Acesso
{
    private $id = null;
    public function features($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
```

e então em resemblant:

```
public function resemblant()
{
    $get = $this->features($this->id);
    return $get['Cidade'];
}
```

Comment: Exatamente **:)**